# New form is not blank when loaded, contains data from previous transaction

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms app that connects to a SQL Server database. On the form to add a new golfer to the golfers table, there are combo boxes for t-shirt size and gender. When a new record is submitted, all the inputs are supposed to clear so that the form is blank when it is re-initialized to add the next record.

The problem is that, when the form is re-initialized, the previously added golfer's gender and t-shirt size are still in their respective combo boxes, while every other input is blank. I've gone through the code, and there's nothing in the load event for the form that would do this. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```vb
'Button on main form to open the input form to add new golfer
Private Sub btnAddGolfer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddGolfer.Click

        'Show Form To Add New Golfer
        frmAddGolfer.ShowDialog()

        'Refresh Form
        frmManageGolfers_Load(sender, e)

    End Sub
_______________________________________________________________
Private Sub frmAddGolfer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Clear any previous data
    ClearForm()

End Sub
______________________________________________________________
'load event for input form
Private Sub btnAddGolfer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddGolfer.Click

        Dim strSelectPlayerID As String = ""
        Dim dtDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable

        Dim strFirstName As String = ""
        Dim strLastName As String = ""
        Dim strStreetAddress As String = ""
        Dim strCity As String = ""
        Dim strState As String = ""
        Dim strZip As String = ""
        Dim strPhoneNumber As String = ""
        Dim strEmail As String = ""
        Dim intGenderID As Integer
        Dim intShirtSizeID As Integer
        Dim intRowsAffected As Integer
        Dim intNextHighestRecordID As Integer

        'Reset control colors
        txtFirstName.BackColor = Color.White
        txtLastName.BackColor = Color.White
        txtAddress.BackColor = Color.White
        txtCity.BackColor = Color.White
        txtState.BackColor = Color.White
        txtZip.BackColor = Color.White
        txtPhoneNumber.BackColor = Color.White
        txtEmailAddress.BackColor = Color.White
        cboGender.BackColor = Color.White
        cboShirtSizes.BackColor = Color.White

        ' this will hold our EXECUTE statement
        Dim cmdAddPlayer As OleDb.OleDbCommand

        ' check to make sure all fields have data. No data no update!
        If Validation(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtZip.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text, txtEmailAddress.Text, CStr(cboGender.SelectedItem), CStr(cboShirtSizes.SelectedItem)) = True Then

            ' open database
            If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then

                ' No, warn the user ...
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection error." & vbNewLine &
                                    "The application will now close.",
                                    Me.Text + " Error",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                ' and close the form/application
                Me.Close()

            End If

            Try
                ' make the connection
                cmdAddPlayer = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()

                'Set Values For stored procedure parameters
                strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text
                strLastName = txtLastName.Text
                strStreetAddress = txtAddress.Text
                strCity = txtCity.Text
                strState = txtState.Text
                strZip = txtZip.Text
                strPhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text
                strEmail = txtEmailAddress.Text
                intGenderID = CInt(cboGender.SelectedIndex) + 1
                intShirtSizeID = CInt(cboShirtSizes.SelectedIndex) + 1

                ' Build the select statement using PK from name selected
                ' Text to build call to stored proc
                cmdAddPlayer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmdAddPlayer.CommandText = "EXECUTE uspAddGolfer '" &
                                          intNextHighestRecordID & "', " &
                                    "'" & strFirstName & "', " &
                                    "'" & strLastName & "', " &
                                    "'" & strStreetAddress & "', " &
                                    "'" & strCity & "', " &
                                    "'" & strState & "', " &
                                    "'" & strZip & "', " &
                                    "'" & strPhoneNumber & "', " &
                                    "'" & txtEmailAddress.Text & "', " &
                                    "'" & intGenderID & "', " &
                                    "'" & intShirtSizeID & "'"

                'EXECUTE stored proc
                cmdAddPlayer = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdAddPlayer.CommandText, m_conAdministrator)

                ' Update the row with execute the statement
                intRowsAffected = cmdAddPlayer.ExecuteNonQuery()

                ' have to let the user know what happened 
                If intRowsAffected = 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("New record added successfully")
                    'clear inputs and close form
                    ClearForm()
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Update failed")
                    'clear inputs and close form
                    ClearForm()
                    Me.Close()
                End If

                ' close the database connection
                CloseDatabaseConnection()

            Catch Ex As Exception

                'Display Error Message To User
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)

            End Try

        End If


    End Sub
______________________________________________________________
    Private Sub ClearForm()

        'Clear form and reset control colors
        txtFirstName.Clear()
        txtLastName.Clear()
        txtAddress.Clear()
        txtCity.Clear()
        txtState.Clear()
        txtZip.Clear()
        txtPhoneNumber.Clear()
        txtEmailAddress.Clear()
        cboGender.ResetText()
        cboShirtSizes.ResetText()

        txtFirstName.BackColor = Color.White
        txtLastName.BackColor = Color.White
        txtAddress.BackColor = Color.White
        txtCity.BackColor = Color.White
        txtState.BackColor = Color.White
        txtZip.BackColor = Color.White
        txtPhoneNumber.BackColor = Color.White
        txtEmailAddress.BackColor = Color.White
        cboGender.BackColor = Color.White
        cboShirtSizes.BackColor = Color.White


    End Sub
```

Comment: Use SQL Parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Someone named "O'Brien" will break your query.  It's better to make a "new" instance of your dialog form when you go display it.

Comment: If you are using Sql Server why are you using Oledb provider? Why not System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: `frmManageGolfers_Load(sender, e)` Why are you sending a button to the load event of a Form?

Comment: Are you sure the Primary Key is not an identity field?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're calling an event handler directly is a good indication that you're doing it wrong.  Don't use default instances at all.  Just do it properly and create a new instance each time.  That way, the load event handler will be executed naturally as a result of the form being loaded.  Create the form with a `Using` statement so it is disposed when you're done with it.

```vb
Using dialogue As New frmAddGolfer
    dialogue.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

If you do it this way, there will be no need to clear the form anyway, because it will be a new form.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do the trick.

```
Private Sub frmAddGolfer_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
```

I am not familiar with ResetText.

Now, to your data access code. Keep your data objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. This is especially important for connections which are precious resources. Using...End Using blocks will do this for you even if there is an error.

```vb
Private Sub btnAddGolfer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddGolfer.Click
    Dim intRowsAffected As Integer
    ' check to make sure all fields have data. No data no update!
    If Not Validation(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtZip.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text, txtEmailAddress.Text, CStr(cboGender.SelectedItem), CStr(cboShirtSizes.SelectedItem)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("All data must be filled in.")
        Return
    End If
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmdAddPlayer As New SqlCommand("uspAddGolfer", cn)
            cmdAddPlayer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtState.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@Zip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtZip.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhoneNumber.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmailAddress.Text
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboGender.SelectedIndex + 1 'Index is an Integer
            cmdAddPlayer.Parameters.Add("@ShirtSize", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboShirtSizes.SelectedIndex + 1
            cn.Open()
            intRowsAffected = cmdAddPlayer.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

    If intRowsAffected = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("New record added successfully")
        Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Update failed")
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

You will have to check your stored procedure to get the correct parameter names and data types.